# Drupal 8: uploading new module causes site break, site does not work shows error

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-modules

Since Drupal 9 is released, after uploading newer versions of Modules in Drupal 8, Drupal site is breaking. Just showing: `An error has been occurred.`

Answer (score 0):

Newer module version for Drupal 8 are made compatible with Drupal 9.

The issue occurs because now, new modules are having their info.yml files have the key:

`core` is replaced by `core_version_requirement`.

Just replace `core_version_requirement` by `core`

eg. module info file: views_data_export.info.yml

Replace:

`core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || 9`

By

`core: '8.x'`

And site will run again.